# Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds (problems with Android 4x)

Tags: android, textview, autoresize

I am testing the following code (developed by Chase) link->
[Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds?answertab=active#tab-top)
and the code works perfect on Android 2x-3x BUT on 4x does not work. By some reason I cannot put comments  directly to the Chase post so I decided to open new  stream..
It would be helpful If any one could suggest why the code stops working on Android 4x?
I tryed myself but stuck with nothing :(.
To run the code I use the following layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
           <chase.test.com.AutoResizeTextView
               android:id="@+id/resizingText"
               android:textSize = "250sp"
               android:gravity = "center"
               android:text = "1 B C  abc d abcd1 abcd2 abcd3 abcd4 abcd5 abcd6 abcd7" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello! would you please help me to address my question to the original post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/5535672#5535672

Comment: this is better solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9714198/1649615